# How to create a folder with an image inside of it PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, mkdir

When the user registers to my site, I want to create a folder with their username and the default profile pic image inside of it. I know how to make a folder, but how do I make a folder with a file in it.

The folder should look something like this:

```
/users/pcoulson/
```

(pcoulson would be the user's username)

and `../pcoulson/` should have the default profile pic in it like this:

```
/users/pcoulson/default-profile_pic.png
```

How would I do this with **PHP**

Comment: Where is default-profile_pic.png to come from? Are you only asking how to copy a file..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dir='users/'.$username;
mkdir($dir);
copy('default-profile_pic.png',$dir.'/default-profile_pic.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['add-user-submit']) && isset($_FILES['image']['name']))
{
    #label the form inputs
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $image = $_FILES["image"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $fileType = $_FILES["image"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $fileSize = $_FILES["image"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["image"]["error"]; // 0 = false | 1 = true
    $kaboom = explode(".", $eventFlyer); // Split file name into an array using the dot
    $fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension

    if(!$fileTmpLoc)
    {
        $error =  "Please insert ALL fields";
    }
    elseif($fileSize > 2097152 )
    {
        $error =  "ERROR: Your file was larger than 2 Megabytes in size.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    }
    elseif(!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $image))
    {
        $error =  "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
    }
    else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1)
    {
        $error =  "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try  again.";
    }
    else
    {

        # move the file to a folder
        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc,  "you file directory ex(../img/users/$username)");

        if($moveResult != true) // there was an error uploading the file to the folder
        {
            $error =  "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
            unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
        }
```

Comment: @user3112869 thanks I had just written a similar script so I had it in the top of my mind

Answer (score 0):

**I propose to save the image in the backing store, your database.**

Doing it this way, the image is 'strongly related' to the user. And it won't get un-related, once the user name changes.

Comment: @Muhammet Absolutely! Using mySQL, you might want to use the types MEDIUMBLOB or MEDIUMBTEXT.

Comment: But file paths in db is the definitely the way to go

Comment: @Muhammet No, actually, there isn't a performance penalty related with storing images in a database.

Answer (score 0):

1. You first have to create the folder
2. Copy the picture to new genereated folder.

Assuming you retireved users data to `$userdata` variable. You can make folder like these
And I assume your `default_pic` is located in the same directory as `users`.

```
 $new_directory = 'users/'.$userdata['username'];
 mkdir($new_directory,0777);
 copy('default-profile_pic.png',$new_directory.'/default-profile_pic.png');
```